# DataGridview RowHeaders Formatecell Autonumber Problem

Tags: vb.net

i have this code in CellFormating Event For datagridview

```
 DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).HeaderCell.Value = CStr(e.RowIndex + 1)
```

i want to get AutoNumber in rowHeader
But i got problem like in this picture
what Should i do ?
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that the values are correct but the first digit is being chopped off when it's displayed. Do you have some right-to-left properties set?

Comment: yes  i have right-to-left properties set .. so what should i do bro

Comment: Increase the `DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth` ?

Comment: What you should do is explain EXACTLY what we can do to reproduce the behaviour you're seeing. If we can reproduce it then we can test to see what fixes it. If you go to the Help Center you will find a link about creating a minimal, reproducible example. That is a requirement for all questions.

Comment: Use the `CellPainting` event to render text in the Row Header